# Parameterization of distorted spirals on cylinder

Tags: differential-geometry

A set of ( evenly spaced right and left handed ) helices on a right circular cylinder are isometrically bent so that the central axis of symmetry has a finite bent radius from straightness.

Is there a standard position / parametrization for bent pipe spirals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $0 < r < R$ are real.

"...a right circular cylinder [...] bent so that the central axis [...] has a finite radius" sounds like wrapping a circular cylinder of radius $r$ around a circular torus of minor radius $r$ and major radius $R$. Unfortunately, this cannot be done isometrically in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ because the "outside" of a torus has positive (Gaussian) curvature and the "inside" has negative curvature.

(This is not just a mathematical nuisance; as I understand it, the difficulty of confining ionized hydrogen in a toroidal magnetic field is a major obstacle to developing controlled fusion as a power source. If helices could be wound around a torus in a manner locally isometric with helices on a cylinder, plasma confinement would be much easier.)

Anyway, the maps
$$
(\rho, \theta) \mapsto (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, \rho)
  \mapsto \bigl((R + r\cos\theta) \cos\rho, (R + r\cos\theta) \sin\rho, r\sin\theta\bigr)
$$
send the plane to the cylinder to the torus; restricting to $\rho = kr\theta + \theta_{0}$ for some real $k$ (the "slope" or "torsion" of the resulting helix on the cylinder) and $\theta_{0}$ (the "phase") arguably gives "standard" bent pipe spirals.

Comment: Apologies, I avoided  using uncommon terminology  "iso-lineal" (retaining  inter node distances only). With it, It is possible to map ( or drape ) a cylindrical helical net onto an inflated automobile tire by scissoring action (shear angle in net  changes) alone to either sign of Gauss curvature or so I believe, correct me if  I am in error. Secondly, I am unable to see what is the difficulty in filament winding on slightly non-circular tubes with geodesic windings with composite fiber rovings.